# C++11 Regex Matching

Tags: c++, regex, gcc

I'm attempting a fairly simple regex match in C++11 (using gcc 4.7.2), but I'm having a large amount of trouble. Attempting to construct a pattern using

```
std::regex unquoted(R"regex(\s*([^",]+)\s*)regex");
```

causes the constructor to throw a `std::regex_error` exception with the code `std::regex_constants::error_escape`. Several regex testers online have no problem with the same expression, and I've tried using different some of the different syntax options to no avail. Is there something fundamentally different about the C++ regex syntax that I'm not grasping?

Comment: You didn't escape the quote in the middle there

Comment: [Yes I did](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#New_string_literals)

Comment: GCC's regex is broken / not implemented.

Comment: [Huh.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) I wish the exception would have said something along those lines instead putting me on a three hour wild goose chase. That's unfortunate.

Comment: It really is unfortunate, clang and msvc already have regex support, but gcc doesn't :(

Comment: [RegEx is now implemented as of GCC 4.9](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53631#c17)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [gcc's stdc++11 implementation status page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) -- regexes are not supported as of gcc 4.8

Edit for posterity: As mentioned in the comments, the regex library is now in `libstdc++` and should be in gcc 4.9 and on.

Comment: I tried building it with clang and got the same result - is that because regardless of which compiler I use, my system is using the same C++ standard library?

Comment: According to http://libcxx.llvm.org/, clang's own C++ standard library should support regex, but is only used by default on OSX.  On other platforms, clang uses the 'native' C++ standard library by default.

Comment: `boost::regex` it is then. Thanks for the help!