# How to match big size list of strings

Tags: python, list

this is a match of strings. Since the sizes are small to med, the operation run fast, but when those size increase, and maybe you place the match into a loop...things become quite frustrating..! ..especially when you manage with strings in the list

```
out = random.sample(range(0, 3000000, 5), 10)
g = random.sample(range(0, 20000, 5), 10)

p = [tmp.append(lu) for lu in g if not lu in out]
```

I've fount this proposition for C++ [using-tr1regex-search-to-match-a-big-list-of-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503372/using-tr1regex-search-to-match-a-big-list-of-strings) I'm going to verify

1. Is there faster alternative code that select the elements in g which doesn't belong to out ?
2. if not, is there any method, library or let the match run on GPU to faster this match ?

thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sets

```
set(g) - set(out)
```

I tried on this

```
out = random.sample(range(0, 100000000, 5), 10000000)
g = random.sample(range(0, 100000000, 5), 10000000)
```

Generating the data took 34s. The set operation took only 1.5s

Comment: effectively with set() code gain with a litte  benefice

Comment: ..not just a litte, a consistent improve. Thanks