# C++11 std::regex_replace() creating regexp with certain string issue

Tags: javascript, c++, regex, c++11, stl

I am currently trying to write a class function that will replace every occurence of a word in a string with an other word , using C++11  lib.

```
void replace(std::string subject, std::string pattern, std::string replacement)
{
    std::regex exp(pattern);
    std::cout <<  std::regex_replace(subject, exp, replacement); 
}


replace(std::string("Hello world"),std::string("world"),std::string("planet"));
```

returns nothing.

I guess that the problem is regular expression , but i have no idea and cannot find anywhere how to make a regexp matching an certain string using ECMAScript or any other availible in .

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: What is the `subject`, `pattern`, and `replacement` you are passing it? Edit your question and include that information otherwise we're just relying on our fabulous clanking crystal balls.

Comment: Hmmmm...this works on VC++10 but not GCC 4.7.2

Comment: It seems like i need to use boost instead. Thank You very much for Your help.

Comment: In JavaScript, it's simply `string.replace(/regexp/g,"repstring");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness: As Xaqq and Captain Obvlious stated in the comments, regex is not yet supported by gcc.

See [this gcc libstdc++ Status Page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) for reference.

On MSVC 2012 your functions works with the desired output.

```
replace("Hello world", "^(.*)world(.*)$", "$1planet$2");
```

> Hello planet

Comment: this producess different output output should be: `Hello planet`

Comment: On gcc version 4.7.2 this doesn't produce any output. Are we running in stdlib implementation issues?

Comment: same on GCC 4.8.1 (no output) and also clang++ 3.3

Comment: @Xaqq not sure but since the OP doesn't seem interested I'm going to follow up on it and if it is I'll submit a bug report

Comment: @CaptainObvlious In fact it seems that regex are not implemented in GCC yet. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059162/c11-regex-matching.

Comment: @Xaqq You read my mind. Just checked and was about to post the same thing lol. Problem solved.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I was afk :P