# Differences in regex support between gcc 4.9.2 and gcc 5.3

Tags: c++, regex, gcc

Can anyone more familiar with gcc point out why the sample below fails to match on gcc 4.9.2 but succeeds on gcc 5.3? Is there anything I can do to alternate the pattern so that it would work (also seems to work fine on VS 2013)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

std::regex pattern("HTTP/(\\d\\.\\d)\\s(\\d{3})\\s(.*)\\r\\n(([!#\\$%&\\*\\+\\-\\./a-zA-Z\\^_`\\|-]+\\:[^\\r]+\\r\\n)*)\\r\\n");

const char* test = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nHost: 192.168.1.72:8080\r\nContent-Length: 86\r\n\r\n";

int main()
{
    std::cmatch results;
    bool matched = std::regex_search(test, test + strlen(test), results, pattern);
    std::cout << matched;
    return 0; 
}
```

I assume I am using something that is not supported in gcc 4.9.2 but was added on or fixed later, but I have no idea where to look it up.

**UPDATE**

Due to the amount of help and suggestions I tried to backtrack the issue instead of just switching to gcc 5. I get correct matches with this modification:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

std::regex pattern("HTTP/(\\d\\.\\d)\\s(\\d{3})\\s(.*?)\\r\\n(?:([^:]+\\:[^\\r]+\\r\\n)*)\\r\\n");

const char* test = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nHost: 192.168.1.72:8080\r\nContent-Length: 86\r\n\r\n";

int main()
{
    std::cmatch results;
    bool matched = std::regex_search(test, test + strlen(test), results, pattern);
    std::cout << matched << std::endl;
    if (matched)
    {
        for (const auto& result : results)
        {
            std::cout << "matched: " << result.str() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So I guess the problem is with the group that matches the HTTP header name. Will check further.

**UPDATE 2**

```
std::regex pattern(R"(HTTP/(\d\.\d)\s(\d{3})\s(.*?)\r\n(?:([!#$&a-zA-Z^_`|-]+\:[^\r]+\r\n)*)\r\n)")
```

is the last thing that works. Adding any of the remaining characters that I had in my group - `%*+-.` (escaped or not epscaped) - breaks it.

Comment: possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059162/c11-regex-matching

Comment: As a sidenote, I recommend raw string literals to limit the onslaught of backslashes.

Comment: @NathanOliver I did not quite catch that - it means the version of `libstdc++` I use with gcc 4.9.2 is to be blamed?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis It is possible.  The answer says it should be fixed by gcc 4.9 but there could be bugs in 4.9.2 since the implementation was still new.

Comment: @user2079303 thanks, hadn't managed to adapt them yet, but it clearly makes things prettier:)

Comment: You could try making your `.*` less greedy as: `.*?`

Comment: @Galik thanks for the advice, but sadly that did not help:(

Comment: Do you get any matches with just `"\\r"`?

Comment: Do you get matches with `"\\r\\n"`?

Comment: @Laurel - thanks for the help, to save the time and answer all the suggestions I posted the last modification that still matches. Seems that the HTTP header name matching part is the pitfall. Not sure why.

Comment: Maybe you need to change `/` to `\\/`

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis, which part(s) are trying to match/extract with the regex?

Comment: All the HTTP response metadata - HTTP version, method, path and headers.

Comment: [You may have been bitten on the butt by a known deficiency in G++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011). I'm not sure, though, since I don't really know how the regex library works, just that it does in G++5.x. In the mean time, if you can't upgrade, use Boost.Regex; it supports more stuff, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

So I know GCC did not support the c++11 regex library until GCC 4.9 officially. See [Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-8-or-earlier-buggy-about-regular-expressions). Since it was so new, it is likely that it had a few bugs to smooth out. Pinning down the exact cause would be difficult, but the problem is in the implementation and not in the regex.

Side note: I remember spending 20 minutes one time trying to figure out what was wrong with my regex when I found the mentioned article and realized that I was using gcc 4.8.*. Since the machine I had to run on wasn't mine, I basically ended up compiling on a different, similar platform with a later version of gcc and a few hacks and then it ran on the target platform.