# Can't get regex_search to find all matches

Tags: regex, c++11

This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278202/getting-stdregex-search-to-work) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15059162/2725810) question, since I am using the newest g++ 6.1.

Here is a simple example I am trying:

```
int main() {
   std::string data = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g";
   std::smatch m;
   regex_search(data, m, std::regex("(\\w)"));
   std::cout << m.size() << std::endl;
   for (auto i = 0U; i != m.size(); i++)
       std::cout << m.position(i) << " " << m[i].str() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

This example outputs 2 as the number of matches, while I would expect 7, since each letter in `data` should match `\w`. How do I fix this?

Also, both matches point to `a` at the beginning of the string.

Comment: how about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667295/how-to-match-multiple-results-using-stdregex

Comment: It does not provide a solution for when the number of matches is not known in advance and I want to know the positions of the matches.

Comment: If you only look at the first half of the first answer then yes, but other answers there are more generic. Particularly St0fF's answer

Comment: You are right. The last reply there does it nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35026140/2725810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an [excerpt from *Finding All Regex Matches* at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/stdregex.html):

> Construct one object by calling the constructor with three parameters: a *string iterator indicating the starting position of the search*, a *string iterator indicating the ending position of the search*, and the *regex object*. If there are any matches to be found, the object will hold the first match when constructed. Construct another iterator object using the default constructor to get an end-of-sequence iterator. You can compare the first object to the second to determine whether there are any further matches. As long as the first object is not equal to the second, **you can dereference the first object to get a `match_results` object**.

So, you can use the following to get matches and their positions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex r(R"(\w)");
    std::string s("a,b,c,d,e,f,g");
    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
                             i != std::sregex_iterator();
                             ++i)
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        std::cout << "Match value: " << m.str() << " at Position " << m.position() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/uA3hFc)

Results:

```
Match value: a at Position 0
Match value: b at Position 2
Match value: c at Position 4
Match value: d at Position 6
Match value: e at Position 8
Match value: f at Position 10
Match value: g at Position 12
```

The regex is better declared with a raw string literal (`R"(\w)"` is a `\w` regex pattern).

Comment: I missed that you could construct an `smatch` from the iterator. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`regex_seach` doesn't provide any facility to scan a whole string, it just stops at first match. Luckily `<regex>` library provided a [`std::regex_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator) which does the job:

```
int main() {
   std::string data = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g";
   std::regex exp =  std::regex("(\\w)");

   auto mbegin = std::sregex_iterator(data.begin(), data.end(), exp);
   auto mend = std::sregex_iterator();

   for (auto it = mbegin; it != mend; ++it)
     cout << it->str() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

The only caveat is that the lifetime of the `std::regex` used must match (at least) the one of the iterator, since `std::regex_iterator` stores a pointer to it internally.

Comment: Can you know the positions of the matches in `data`?

Comment: cppreference is your friend, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator

Comment: I looked and I think you can't using the iterators approach. If you can, please modify your example to output the position of each match. I will then accept your answer.